# Can I use Gherkin keyword Background in Cypress to only run for certain "tagged" Scenarios

Tags: cypress, gherkin, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I use Cypress Automation with features written in Gherkin via the Cypress-Cucumber-preprocessor.

We recently refactored the features to use `Background` at the top of each feature file so that it is called with each `Scenario`.

However, now we need only certain tests in the scenario to utilize the Background at the top.

#### Research

I've been reviewing Cypress documentation and cannot see if this is possible.

#### Question

Can the Gherkin keyword [`Background`](https://cucumber.io/docs/gherkin/reference/#background) be limited to only some scenarios that have certain tags (e.g. `@NormalLoad` or `@HighLoad`) ?

Answer (score 4):

The `Background` statement would run in every scenario of this feature.

Instead you could use the *hook* [`Before`](https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/?lang=javascript#before) targeting a specific tag on the feature. This way the script would be doing the same as `Background`.

Other than `Background` the `Before` hook run on any feature that has the appropriate tag(s).